# Styled Components - Best practice to prevent recurrences

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I'm new to styled components. Let's say I have the following list of styled components/typography - as you can see `margin` & `color` are used the same within every component. What's the best practice here to prevent these recurrences and only define it once? Is there a way to extend some styled component, just like `styled(SomeComponent)`, but without copying the tag?

```
export const H1 = styled.h1`
    font: ${props => props.theme.font};
    font-size: 12.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: -.1rem;
    color: ${props => props.isBlack ? props.theme.black : props.theme.white};
    margin: ${props => props.m};
`;

export const H2 = styled.h2`
    font: ${props => props.theme.font};
    font-size: 7.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1;
    color: ${props => props.isBlack ? props.theme.black : props.theme.white};
    margin: ${props => props.m};
`;

export const Link = styled.div`
    font: ${props => props.theme.font};
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1;
    color: ${props => props.isBlack ? props.theme.black : props.theme.white};
    margin: ${props => props.m};
`;

export const Text = styled.div`
    font: ${props => props.theme.font};
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1;
    color: ${props => props.isBlack ? props.theme.black : props.theme.white};
    margin: ${props => props.m};
`;
```

Comment: what's wrong with `styled(SomeComponent)` ?

Comment: you can also import `css` from `styled-components` and use in any component you want

Comment: @zb22 using `styled(SomeComponent)` will also copy `someComponent`'s tag, so if its tag is a `div` and I want to have the css for my `h1`, I'm not able to use the `h1` tag.

Comment: @zb22 what do you mean by importing css? can I use sass variables or mixins withing the styled component?

Comment: check this: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css